# Open file located client side with HTML href

Tags: html, file

All the clients of our intranet have the same network share `S:` to access file located server side.

I want to create a button that can open documents (PDF, ODT, ...) directly from this location. So they should not browse the shared folder but simply click on this button.

Is it even possible?

I already tried things like that

```
<a href="S:\\test.txt" target="_self"><button>TEST</button></a>

<a href="file://S:/test.txt" target="_self"><button>TEST</button></a>

<a href="file:///S:\\test.txt" target="_self"><button>TEST</button></a>
```

But none of this works.

I do not know if this is possible, I am just asking.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot put `<button>` inside `<a>`.** Instead make the `<button>` go to that specific URI using JavaScript:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='S:\\test.txt';">TEST</button>
<button onclick="location.href='file:\/\/\/S:\/test.txt';">TEST</button>
```

Also see the last one, which should be `<button>` not `<butto>`!